# Google Maps update url LatLngBounds and zoom while camera move

Tags: google-maps, ionic4

I am currently working on ionic native google maps building weather map . Basically i want to get LatLngBounds and zoom level  while camera move then pass those data to url even shows data on map .

example every time when move map  and zoom level, the url dynamically updates .

http://www.xxxxxxxx.net/map#lat=-25.87899&lng=-42.45117&zoom=4

My code :

```
     getData(){

         ////Here should pass LatLngBounds in url ////

        this.http.get('xxxxxxx/MetarJSON.php?bbox='','','',''' ,{},{}).then(data=>{

        let DataJson = JSON.parse(data.data)

        for (let datas of DataJson['features']) {

          this.points.push({ lng: datas.geometry.coordinates[0], lat: datas.geometry.coordinates[1] });

        }

        for (let i = 0; i <  DataJson.features.length; i++) {

          let coords = DataJson.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
          this.latLng = new LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]);
          this.icoa = DataJson.features[i].properties.id
          this.rawOb = DataJson.features[i].properties.rawOb
          let fltcat = DataJson.features[i].properties.fltcat


          let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
            position: this.latLng,
            title:fltcat,
            icon: icons
          })



        }


        })

      }

      loadMap() {

        let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
          camera: {
             target: {
               lat: 33.263,
               lng: 44.232
             },
             zoom: 6,
           }
        };

        this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);


  ////   Here l get LatLngBounds but when l move map the lat and lng aren't update

     let chec1=  this.map.getVisibleRegion().farLeft.lat
     let chec2=  this.map.getVisibleRegion().farLeft.lng
      console.log(chec1,chec2)
      }
```

[Ionic Google map native plugin Doc](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/tree/master/documents)

Answer (score 0):

l found solution while move map to update LatLngBounds . used GoogleMapsEvent constants

depending on doc , and he is working fine

```
   this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.CAMERA_MOVE).subscribe(()=>{

          let left=  this.map.getVisibleRegion().northeast.lat
          let leftbottom=  this.map.getVisibleRegion().northeast.lng
          let right=  this.map.getVisibleRegion().southwest.lat
          let rightbottom=  this.map.getVisibleRegion().southwest.lng
           console.log(left,leftbottom , right ,rightbottom )
        })
```